# What is the proper term for "permanent world"?

Tags: mmo, first-person-shooter, terminology

How to name the fact that for a MMO game there's one big session, the same things are happening for all the players, you log out and after two days log in to the same place as the same person ?

I'd like to mention that not all MMO games are constructed this way, for example majority of MMOFPS games are based on lobby/separated severs system, so prefix "MMO" isn't necessarily equal to "onesessionism".

I myself can't think of any better expression than "permanent world".

Comment: The only MMOFPS I know of is Planetside, which very much did have a persistent world.

Comment: I think the best example of a permanent world is [Eve Online](http://www.eveonline.com/), where all players are all in one server/world.

Comment: True, but not an answer to this question.

Comment: oh, but there is actually a real question on what geneotech says?

Comment: Yes, he asked which was the proper term, and he has in fact been answered by @Bane

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's "persistent world".

Also note that there is phasing, the world is usually divided into many zones all ran on different servers. Also, this isn't really gamedev related at all.

Comment: yes of course I am aware of this fact, I described it as seen by eyes of a player.

Comment: Yep, OK, I was just saying.

Comment: It's not true that by default there is phasing.

Comment: Well, in most bigger MMORPGs there is phasing... And my statement wasn't really definitive, first I said that phasing exists, and then I said that it is _usually_ applied.

Answer (score 0):

I've also come across terms like **open world** and the opposite

> lobby/separated severs system

as  **matchmaking**.